# Installation of Composer on Raspbian Jessie failed

Tags: php, curl, debian, composer-php, raspbian

After following the installation guide on the composer-website

```
php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"
php -r "if (hash_file('SHA384', 'composer-setup.php') === 'e115a8dc7871f15d853148a7fbac7da27d6c0030b848d9b3dc09e2a0388afed865e6a3d6b3c0fad45c48e2b5fc1196ae') { echo 'Installer verified'; } else { echo 'Installer corrupt'; unlink('composer-setup.php'); } echo PHP_EOL;"
php composer-setup.php
php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');"
```

PHP just seems to stop working. After a few minutes I cancelled with Ctrl+C.

Tried the same with curl but getting the following error:

```
pi@rasppi-09:~ $ curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | sudo php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
All settings correct for using Composer
PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(https://getcomposer.org/versions): failed to open stream: Connection timed out in - on line 762
PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in - on line 508
None of the 0 stable version(s) of Composer matches your PHP version (5.6.24-0+deb8u1 / ID: 50624)
```

As far as I can see, there is kind of timeout but I actually have no idea why. I'm using a proxy for HTTP/S and FTP, but it works flawless for other stuff.

Comment: Did you try to get the installer with wget command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was kind of a proxy problem, php didn't used the defined proxys.

Thanks to Mirdrack (see comment), I did it with wget.